# In R, read.config is escaping a google-service-key but I dont want it to

Tags: r, my.cnf

For my job, I have to use an .my.cnf file to pass a password key into my R code, since I cannot (for security reasons) keep my password key in the R code itself. So I have R code that looks like this:

```
library(configr)
my_configs = read.config(file = "~/.my.cnf")
my_googleservicekey = my_configs$api_authentication$googleServiceKeyJsonString
```

Separately, I have a .my.cnf file saved on my computer, and that file looks like this:

```
[api authentication]
googleServiceKeyJsonString = {\r\n \"type"\: \"service_account\",\r\n \"project_id\": ...  ... \r\n}
```

where the ... ... signifies that the actual googleServiceKey is much longer. This key was provided by a coworker of mine, and needs to be set **exactly** as such in the R variable *my_googleservicekey*. However, when I save the key like this in the .my.cnf file, and read it into R in the manner that I did, I get the following:

```
> my_googleservicekey
[1] "{\\r\\n \\\"type\\\": \\\"service_account\\\",\\r\\n \\\"project_id\\\": ... ... \\r\\n}"
```

So what happens is, sometime when *read.config(file = "~/.my.cnf")* is run, the 
object/string I passed/saved into the .my.cnf file looks like it had all of the quotes and backslashes escaped, and as a result I don't have the correct variable in R.

My question then is this:

**Is it possible to save the key in the .my.cnf and have read.config in R read the key EXACTLY as it is saved in the .my.cnf file, so that it doesn't add the additional escapes?**

Thanks in advance for any help with this!!

EDIT: In particular, are there any parameters to R's read.config function, or any other functions in R that could help out with this?

Comment: looks like a `JSON` format, maybe you just need to parse it with `fromJSON`

Comment: yes it is a json format - does fromJSON have a way to remove the extra unescaped characters?

Comment: @Canovice It won't affect have an effect while reading. This is how a `json` when read in R looks like, i.e, while you print the json object it will have an extra `\` but it does not alter the structure of the json. Just prints it in a different manner.