# In R, how to unescape a JSON object saved in a string

Tags: r, escaping

I have the following JSON saved as a string in R, however due to the way that the string is being read into R, the string is *escaped* twice. Here it is:

```
> myJsonString = "{\\r\\n \\\"type\\\": \\\"service_account\\\",\\r\\n \\\"project_id\\\": \\\"3456\\\" \\r\\n}"
> class(myJsonString)
[1] "character"
```

and I would simply like to get this to look like this:

```
> myBetterJsonString = "{\r\n \"type\": \"service_account\",\r\n \"project_id\": \"3456\" \r\n}"
> class(myBetterJsonString)
[1] "character"
```

This is related to a separate post I made here - [In R, read.config is escaping a google-service-key but I dont want it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48819951/in-r-read-config-is-escaping-a-google-service-key-but-i-dont-want-it-to) - however I realized that my problem could be simplified to this. Any help would be appreciated!

**Note**: my actual string is much longer. I've checked how the string looks and how it should look and the only differences appear to be:

- one extra \ before the \r and \n
- two extra \ before the \ that should exist to escape the quotes ""

As always, thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: you're correct - i just updated it thanks!

Comment: `jsonlite::fromJSON(gsub("\\\\\"", "\"", gsub("\\\\n", "\n", gsub("\\\\r", "\r", s))))` works for me for parsing the string. Do without the `fromJSON` if you just want/need the string. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: thanks this is great

Comment: I found an edge case actually that i'm dealing with - theres a single "\\\n" that i simply need to turn back into "\\n". It comes after "----" so in full it's "----\\\n" that I need to update to "----\\n" but im struggling with this

Comment: If it is different yet escaped the same, that suggests something is wrong with the escaping mechanism. Perhaps you should look at a different mechanism for getting the data in the first place?

Comment: I have a separate post for that actually - im using Rs read.config function to read in a JSON object from a .my.cnf file into R, and I dont want it to escape the string, but im struggling with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `{stringi}` package has the function you want to do this:

```r
myJsonString = "{\\r\\n \\\"type\\\": \\\"service_account\\\",\\r\\n \\\"project_id\\\": \\\"3456\\\" \\r\\n}"
stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(myJsonString)
#> [1] "{\r\n \"type\": \"service_account\",\r\n \"project_id\": \"3456\" \r\n}"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>